# Custom shortcut for krunner in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, 14.10, kde4

The default shortkey is Alt-F2. How to edit that?

I have added a custom shortcut for `krunner`, but I want one to toggle: show or hide, just like ALT-F2, not just open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer here, under [ALT+F2 App launcher Hotkey remapping](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=90875#p173512).

[image]